# custom menu control in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c

i want to create the custom menu control in UIWebView, by using

```
- (void) setUpCustomMenu 
{

    Class cls1 = NSClassFromString(@"UIMenuController");
    Class cls2 = NSClassFromString(@"UIMenuItem");

    if (cls1 && cls2)

    if ([UIMenuController instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setMenuItems:)]) 
    {
        UIMenuItem* item1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Menu Item" action:@selector(myMenuAction:)];
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, nil];;
        [item1 release];
    }

}
```

but i am unable to create custom menu, please guide me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extend the system-editing menu

```
NSMutableArray *extraItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIMenuItem *boldItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@”Bold” 
                                                  action:@selector(bold:)];
[extraItems addObject:boldItem];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuItems = extraItems;
```

UIWebView
Extend the system-editing menu

```
// For your UIWebView subclass:
 - (void)bold:(id)sender {
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScript:@”document.execCommand(‘Bold’)];
}

 - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(bold:))
      return YES;
    return [super canPerformAction:action
                        withSender:sender];
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works. Do you have an idea about how to remove the copy menu from the UIWebView.

Comment: - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
 BOOL retValue = NO;
 //ColorTile *theTile = [self colorTileForOrigin:currentSelection];
 
 if (action == @selector(paste:) )
  retValue = NO;
 else if ( action == @selector(cut:) || action == @selector(copy:) )
  retValue = NO;
 else
  retValue = [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
 return retValue;
}

Comment: @aartiGarg return NO in - (BOOL)canPerformAction:withSender: if the action is @selector(copy:)

Comment: i want that nobody copy any content from the web view and paste it somewhere else like in safari.

Comment: Then maybe you could try some CSS scripts like disabling text modify with --webkit

Comment: do you have any example for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass UIWebView, watch this in WWDC 2011 videos: [Rich Text Editing in Safari on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=511)

Comment: Will you please give me an example for the above.

Comment: @aartiGarg I've added a new answer for detail.