# Selecting text in PDF

Tags: ios, pdf

I know there are hundreds of questions about it and I have been digging into them since last two days but could not found any complete solution. What I want to do is to let the user select text in a PDF file and give options of copy, etc. This functionality is provided by PSPDF library but PSPDF contains overwhelming amount of functionalities that are of no use for me. I have checked ThatPDF and PDFKitten but I could not select text as I can do with PSPDF. Is there anyway I can perform this operation the way PSPDF does?

Any help or or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You could easily use `UIWebView` to show your PDF. It provides these functionality be default. Or do you more features than show and select?

Comment: Yeah there are some more features which are related and also not directly related to showing PDF and can't be done using webview.

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not a PDF expert, but I already did PDF creation in PHP and Obj-C... Might have an idea :)

Comment: Related to displaying PDF, selecting and searching text. Unrelated, playing video, audio, displaying map and many more. The way UIWebView provides interaction with PDF is also not desirable.

Comment: You should use different views (classes) for different types of media. So for displaying, selecting and searching a PDF, UIWebView is suitable. But if you don't like it, I can't help you, I'm sorry :) UIWebView is actually quite well configurable and I used it quite a long time to display PDFs

Comment: Problem with WebView is the user Interaction and lack of full control over content. Because of which I can't use UIWebView. For ex As I mentioned in question, I have some more custom options to display with copy when user selects the text. I also have to track user interaction on PDF file to display media.

Comment: I understand that you don't like to use webView. I don't like it either. Nevertheless adding menu items is absolutely possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394072/custom-menu-control-in-uiwebview I also think that user interaction is trackable, but I don't have experience with it! Keep me up to date, if you find a suitable class for you, I'm also interested. Sorry I couldn't help you